# Multiple functions updating datetime stamp in multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

I am trying to update multiple cells based on input in each. The first works fine with a specific text from dropdown but I get no results on the other remaining 3. Here is the script I have:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if(sheet.getName() !== 'Dec2021' || e.range.columnStart !== 3 || e.range.rowStart < 0) return;
  e.range.offset(0,7).setValue(e.value == '2-Ready' ? new Date() : null)
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if(sheet.getName() !== 'Dec2021' || e.range.columnStart !== 8 || e.range.rowStart < 0) return;
  e.range.offset(0,9).setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date())
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if(sheet.getName() !== 'Dec2021' || e.range.columnStart !== 7 || e.range.rowStart < 0) return;
  e.range.offset(0,9).setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date())
}

function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if(sheet.getName() !== 'Dec2021' || e.range.columnStart !== 6 || e.range.rowStart < 0) return;
  e.range.offset(0,9).setValue(typeof e.value == 'object' ? null : new Date())
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

In an Apps Script project, each global function should have a unique name. To make your code work, you will have to combine the functions into one as shown in the [onEdit(e) best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219) post.

But there are much better ways to implement timestamps. You may want to take a look at scripts such as [yetAnotherTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135269995?msgid=135276870), [timestampMultipleRanges_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135020393?msgid=135043616) and [timestampMultipleColumns_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/28719648?msgid=28825318).

Also see [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).