# Why don't my onEdit script keep runing?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm new to coding and google app scripts. I write a onEdit script, and when I run it, it shows me. "Start running", and 1 second later "Finished". It doesn't show me any error. How do I make it keep running? This is my script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = s.getActiveCell();
  if (s.getName="Reading Log" && r.getColumn() !=2) {
    r.offset(0,-1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yy")
  }
}
```

What I want to do is that I have a google sheet reading log. On sheet 'Reading Log' column 2, I'm going to put the name of book or article I read. I want the script automatically fill in the date I enter the name into column 1 next to it. I'll be happy if someone could help me fix it or write a better script. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. The script has several problems, missing parenthesis, wrong operator, wrong object. If you haven't done yet, please start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers. If you need further help, show what you have tried to fix the errors / debug the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onEdit(e)` function is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Do not run the code in the script editor. It runs automatically when you *manually edit* the spreadsheet.

To insert a timestamp when column `B` is edited, fix line 4 like this:

```
  if (s.getName() === 'Reading Log' && r.getColumn() === 2) {
```

For better performance, use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). See `onEdit(e)` [best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: Thank you! But why do you use three equals sign instead of two? And ' ' instead of " "?

Comment: See [Equality comparisons and sameness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) and [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript).