# I can not remove data validation with 2 criterias - Function onEdit(e)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers, data-validation

I would like to run function onEdit(e) to remove Data validation with these 2 criterias as below:

1. Remove for columns G,H,I,K if L is "no need".
2. Remove for columns M,N,O,Q if R is "no need<2>"

My script runs well for the first criteria.
However, it does not work for the second.
I can not figure out the solution.
Pls help me to correct the script.

```
function onEdit(e) {
 var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var values = sheet.getRange(`L${row}`).getValues()[0];
  var r = sheet.getRangeList(["G", "H", "I", "K"].map(f => `${f}${row}`));
  if (values.includes("no need")) {
    r.clearDataValidations().setValue("no need");
  } else {
    var rules = ["'Data validation'!$G$5:$G$1003", "'Data validation'!$H$5:$H$1003", "'Data validation'!$I$5:$I$1003", "'Data validation'!$K$5:$K$1003"];
    r.getRanges().forEach((rr, i) => rr.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(e.source2.getRange(rules[i]), true).build()));
  }
  var values1 = sheet.getRange(`R${row1}`).getValues()[0];
  var r1 = sheet.getRangeList(["M", "N", "O", "Q"].map(f1 => `${f1}${row1}`));
  if (values1.includes("no need<2>")) {
    r1.clearDataValidations().setValue("no need<2>");
  } else {
    var rules1 = ["'Data validation'!$M$5:$M$1003", "'Data validation'!$N$5:$N$1003", "'Data validation'!$O$5:$O$1003", "'Data validation'!$Q$5:$Q$1003"];
    r1.getRanges().forEach((rr1, i) => rr1.setDataValidation(SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(e.source.getRange(rules1[i]), true).build()));
  }
}
```

Many thanks

Here is my GG sheet link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1osCKdZsvaKTFJyD2wfcCoQtIfGxTR6ovt9eE7zabyzs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Remove for columns G,H,I,K if L is "no need".
> 2. Remove for columns M,N,O,Q if R is "no need<2>"

Use `Array.includes()` and the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e`, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* When the value 'no need' is entered in column L, removes data validation
* in columns G, H, I, K in the active row.
*
* When the value 'no need<2>' is entered in column R, removes data validation
* in columns M, N, O, Q in the active row.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  if (!e.range || !['no need', 'no need <2>'].includes(e.value)) {
    return;
  }
  const columnsToClear = {
    12: ['G', 'H', 'I', 'K'],
    18: ['M', 'N', 'O', 'Q'],
  }[e.range.columnStart];
  if (!columnsToClear) {
    return;
  }
  const rangeList = e.range.getSheet().getRangeList(
    columnsToClear
      .map(columnLabel => `${columnLabel}${e.range.rowStart}`)
  );
  rangeList.clearDataValidations();
  e.source.toast(`Cleared data validations in ${rangeList.getRanges().length} cells.`);
}
```

See [onEdit(e) best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).