# Clear cells based on checkbox repeated Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have checkboxes in columns A, E, H, L, O, S, V, and Z
I have a script that is working which allows me to check the box in a2 and it deletes data in e2 and f2. I then am able to reverse the script so selecting the checkbox in e2 will delete data in a2 and b2. Perfect.

The problem is I need it to do it for 29 rows and I can't figure out how to make it work unless I duplicate the script 232 times.

So the checkboxes go together as follows;

- A needs to delete E and F - while E needs to delete A and B
- H needs to delete L and M - while L needs to delete H and I
- O needs to delete S and T - while S needs to delete O and P
- V needs to delete Z and AA - while Z needs to delete V and W

I hope this makes sense.

Is there an easy way to do this or am I stuck duplicating the script?

```
function onEdit9(e) {
 var ss = e.source;

 var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

 var cell = e.range;

 if (activeSheet.getName() == "OPEN" && cell.getA1Notation() == "E2" && cell.isChecked()){

   activeSheet.getRange("a2:b2").clearContent();

 }
}
function onEdit10(e) {

 var ss = e.source;

 var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

 var cell = e.range;


 if (activeSheet.getName() == "OPEN" && cell.getA1Notation() == "A2" && cell.isChecked()){

   activeSheet.getRange("E2:F2").clearContent();

 }
}
```

Note: the `onEdit9` and `onEdit10` are due to other onEdit scripts that are running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You only need, and should only have, exactly one `onEdit(e)` function that handles all columns, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* A needs to delete E and F
* E needs to delete A and B
* H needs to delete L and M
* L needs to delete H and I
* O needs to delete S and T
* S needs to delete O and P
* V needs to delete Z and AA
* Z needs to delete V and W
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  const logic = {
    1: [5, 6],
    5: [1, 2],
    8: [12, 13],
    12: [8, 9],
    15: [19, 20],
    19: [15, 16],
    22: [26, 27],
    26: [22, 23],
  };
  const colNum = e.range.columnStart;
  let sheet;
  if (!Object.keys(logic).includes(String(colNum))
    || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(OPEN)$/i)
    || !e.range.isChecked()) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, logic[colNum][0], 1, logic[colNum][1] - logic[colNum][0] + 1).clearContent();
}
```

See [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://web.archive.org/web/20131204221336/http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Don%27t_Repeat_Yourself) and these [onEdit(e) best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).