# Timestamp on change of another range

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a Planning sheet that I use to follow budgets that are reported every week.
I'd like to have K7:18 stamped with a date when there is a change in the corresponding cell of I7:I18 range.
I cannot use onEdit function cause of other scripts currently running. I had no luck with onChange until now, though I'm not skilled with Google Apps Script.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Per your comment "When I started expanding the datasets within the spreadsheet, it would execute "successfully" but the dates would be updated sporadically. After days of troubleshooting I had to give up on the approach."  it would helpful to understand more  about the data as well as the other script.

Answer (score 1):

When you have two `onEdit(e)` functions in the same script project, it is indeed the case that only [one of them will run](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66906642/13045193).

The simplest pattern to combine two `onEdit(e)` functions is to rename the existing functions to `doFirstThing_(e)` and `doSecondThing_(e)`, and then call them like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  doFirstThing_(e);
  doSecondThing_(e);
}
```

See [onEdit(e) best practices](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Alternatively, use a timestamp script that can handle multiple sheets and ranges, such as my [yetAnotherTimestamp_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/234619663?msgid=234634959) script.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

I've already tried this approach, and for unknown reason it does not work reliably. 

When I started expanding the datasets within the spreadsheet, it would execute "successfully" but the dates would be updated sporadically. 
After days of troubleshooting I had to give up on the approach.

I'll take a look at your script. Thanks!