# How to get Sheets to recognize dates that are entered without any separators?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates, date

I want to enter dates in `yyyymmdd` format, but have Google Sheets format the values as `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I don't want to enter any dashes (or slashes, or spaces) because it slows down my data entry, but instead have Sheets add them automatically between the year, month, day.

For example, I want to type **20231203** and see **2023-12-03** in the cell.

I tried using the date format `yyyy-mm-dd` but it converts `20231203` to `57291-02-23`.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how fast you type.  Would be interesting to know if [the script-based solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173141) can keep up.  I can't outpace it myself...

Answer (score 4):

One approach might be to use one column formatted as plain text to enter the dates in yyyymmdd format, then use an array formula in another column to generate the dates in the correct format. For instance:

1. Select column A and use Format/Number/Plain text to force all cells to plain text
2. Select column B and use Format/Number/Custom date and time and select the yyyy-mm-dd format, then in B1 use the following formula: `=arrayformula(iferror(date(left(A1:A,4),mid(A1:A,5,2),right(A1:A,2))))`

Comment: Good catch. Probably worth stating that if you wanted to do something similar with dates in ddmmyyyy format then in this case you would need to use plain text format for the input cells, as otherwise you'd run into problems with the leading zero of single digit days being omitted (and so all the digits being out by one)

Answer (score 2):

You can format those numbers so that they look like `2023-12-03` like this:

**Format > Number > Custom number format >** `0000-00-00`

That will not convert the values to dates, though. The underlying value will remain a largish number like `20231203` (twenty million and change.)

To convert the values to dates, use this formula in another column:

```
=to_date(value(to_text(D2)))
```

You can format the new column as `yyyy-MM-dd` and use it in formulas downstream instead of referring to the original column.

See [Working with date and time values in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219).

Answer (score 2):

You can enter numbers as numbers...

Enter `20231225` in A1, and in an adjacent cell, add the following formula.

```
=DATE(A1/10000, MOD(INT(A1/100),100), MOD(A1,100))
```

---

If your dates are all in this century, you could save two keystrokes per entry with:

```
=DATE( 100 + A1/10000, MOD(INT(A1/100),100), MOD(A1,100))
```

This converts `231225` to the SS's value for `25 Dec 2023`.

Merry Christmas!

---

I'm indebted to other answers here for showing `ARRAYFORMULA()` and its use. (Nice!) Wish this had been available decades ago when creating spreadsheets was a frequent task.

Comment: Very nice, I [adapted your formula to a script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173141) to eliminate the need for a helper column.

Answer (score 1):

[@FE2O3's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173128) is elegant in its simplicity, employing a single mathematical formula to convert the initial number into a datevalue, without the need for special formatting.

It requires a helper column, as do the other solutions including [my regex-based one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173118), so I adapted it into a custom function that uses an onEdit simple trigger.

Sheets will return the datevalue in the default date format if the column number format is set to automatic (default). Alternatively, the column can be custom formatted (eg. `yyyy-mm-dd`).

## FE2O3's Formula

```
=DATE(n/10000, MOD(INT(n/100),100), MOD(n,100))
```

## Custom  Function

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (e) {
 
    const range = e.range;
    const value = e.value || range.getValue().toString();
    const sheet = range.getSheet();
    const col = range.getColumn();
    const names = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2"];
    const columns = [ 2 ];
 
    if ((names.indexOf(sheet.getName()) > -1) &&        // valid sheet
        (columns.indexOf(col) > -1) &&                  // valid column
         value.match(/^(2[01]\d\d[01]\d[0-3]\d)$/)) {   // date string          

      // number to datevalue formula  
      // @Fe2O3 https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173128
      // =DATE(n/10000, MOD(INT(n/100),100), MOD(n,100))
   
      const date = [(value/10000).toFixed(0),
                    (value/100).toFixed(0) % 100,
                    (value % 100)];
 
      const newDate = new Date([date]);

      if ((newDate.getFullYear() == date[0]) &&
          (newDate.getMonth()+1 == date[1])  &&
          (newDate.getDate() == date[2])) {
       
        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), col).setValue(newDate);

      } else {

        sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), col).setFontColor("red");

        throw new Error("Invalid or mismatched newDate parsed from e.value:" +  '\n' +
                        "e.value:  " + value + '\n' + "newDate:  " + newDate + '\n' );
                       
      }    
   
    }

  }

}
```

## Conditions

The conditions for the script to modify an edited value:

1. The value is a group of 8 numbers that follow the pattern `2###m#d#` where `m` is either `0` or `1` and `d` is a a number from `0` to `3`
2. The value is in a sheet whose name is in the array `names`. To remove this condition, remove `(names.indexOf(sheet.getName()) > - 1)`
3. The value is in a column number that is in the array `columns`. To remove this condition, remove `(columns.indexOf(col) > -1)`

Comment: Very nice. Thank you for the mention. :-)... It's a bit of code... Hope the OP and subsequent readers have lots of data to recoup the keystrokes! `:-)` Cheers!

Comment: I am assuming the question is based on significant data entry given the fact that they are complicating their life in order to avoid an additional 2 keystrokes per date entered, and the relevant keys are co-located on the numpad.  The code would be shorter knowing the specific parameters of the use case but, In any case,  the lion's share of the keystrokes invested are mine and yours rather than theirs ;-)

Comment: You can replace the `Math.log()` bit with `e.value.length`. See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: The best practice is to use `e` instead of API calls like `range.getValue()`. One complication is that `e.value` is always a text string. It represents the text the user entered in the cell, verbatim, and is thus never a number. Because of this, `Number.isInteger(e.value)` will always return `false`. I would usually test with something like `e.value && e.value.match(/^(2[01]\d\d[01]\d[0-3]\d)$/)`. To do it with coercion to a number, get the value with `Number(e.value)` and additionally test the result with `Number.isNaN()`.

Comment: Formula edited to test for a valid date. If the value passes initial tests but fails to parse to a valid date (too many months/days etc) then an error is thrown in the log  and the edited cell font is changed to red instead but no other transformation is performed.

Answer (score 0):

A similar approach (but longer) to [@The God of Biscuits' solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173116) uses REGEXREPLACE to divide up the initial value.

Initial value can be a number or text, and results column should be formatted as dates.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IFERROR(
     REGEXREPLACE(
       TEXT(1/(1/A:A), "@"),
       "^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})",
        "$1-$2-$3")/1))
```