# Custom function to move and delete a row isn't doing anything

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script bound to my Google spreadsheet with a simple onEdit(e) trigger that isn't working.

The script is supposed to move the edited row to `Closed Cases`, then delete the original row, if the following conditions in the active sheet are all true:

1. The active sheet is named `11th Grade`
2. The edited cell is in the checkbox Column 14 / N
3. The checkbox is selected / `true`

When I make changes to `11th Grade` the script always completes successfully but the row is never moved or deleted.

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var ss = e.source;
  var activatedSheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var activatedCell = ss.getActiveSelection();
  var activatedCellRow = activatedCell.getRow();
  var activatedCellColumn = activatedCell.getColumn();
  var activatedCellValue = activatedCell.getValue();
 
  var input = ss.getSheetByName("11th Grade"); // source sheet
  var closed = ss.getSheetByName("Closed Cases"); // target sheet

  if (activatedSheetName == input.getName() && activatedCellColumn == 14 && activatedCellValue == "True") {

    // insert a new row at the second row of the target sheet
    closedlosed.insertRows(2,1);

    // move the entire source row to the second row of target sheet
    var rangeToMove = input.getRange(/*startRow*/ activatedCellRow, /*startColumn*/ 1, /*numRows*/ 1, /*numColumns*/ input.getMaxColumns());
    rangeToMove.moveTo(closedlosed.getRange("A2"));
    
    // delete row from source sheet
    input.deleteRows(activatedCellRow,1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working version of your script that you can review to see how it differs from your approach.

### Script

[Sample Spreadsheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eXOfB5hsP7voJmvDujAVMbZ87fTHZ7vjFrmOftoC8wk/edit#gid=2100307022)

```
function onEdit(e) {

  const ss = e.source;
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const row = range.getRow();
    
  const input = "11th Grade";
  const output = "Closed Cases";
  const valueCol = 4;
  const checkCol = 14;
  
  if ((sheet.getName() == input) &&          //  was the right sheet edited?  
      (range.getColumn() == checkCol) &&     //  was the checkbox column edited?
      (range.getValue() == true) &&          //  is the checkbox selected?  
      (out = ss.getSheetByName(output))) {   //  does the destination sheet exist?

    out.insertRowAfter(1);
    sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(out.getRange("A2"));
    sheet.deleteRow(row);

  }

}
```

[image: Example of Script in action with the source and target sheets displayed]

[image: Google Apps Script Simple onEdit(e) Trigger]

## Troubleshooting

If you have a script that is not working as intended, you can add logging with `Logger.log()` to determine what is working/not working and where.

If the conditions are passing but the move isn't being performed, you know that the issue is with the statements following the conditions.

Here is an example that logs the success or failure of the if statement conditions.

```
if (x) {
  Logger.log("success");
} else {
  Logger.log("failure");
}
```

[image: Shows a portion of the script containing the if statement with the addition of an else statement and logging for success and failure.]

Comment: That is not part of what I need to do.  I removed Line 19 and it still is not completing (copying, pasting and deleting)

Comment: @Kelly is there a failure in the execution log?  If not you need to troubleshoot what you are doing differently.  You could add some simple logging to see if the conditions pass.  I can't tell from here what you are doing that is different but if you screenshot your code I'm sure I can point out the issue.  I clarified some basic troubleshooting steps with an example in an [edit to my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173124).

Comment: @kelly I added a [working sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eXOfB5hsP7voJmvDujAVMbZ87fTHZ7vjFrmOftoC8wk/edit#gid=2100307022) using your source data.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question calls nine `SpreadsheetApp` methods *every* time *any* value in the spreadsheet is edited, before actually getting to its business, and uses six API calls to move the row. All these API calls slow things down. The event queue only will only handle two events at a time, so if you tick checkboxes in quick succession, chances are that some rows do not get moved even if they meet the conditions.

You can speed it up by orders of magnitude by taking more advantage of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) `e`, like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user manually edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  moveRowConditionally_(e);
}


/**
* Moves a row from '11th Grade' to the top of 'Closed Cases' when a
* checkbox in column N is ticked and the row has 'Success' in column D.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function moveRowConditionally_(e) {
  if (e.value !== 'TRUE' || e.range.columnStart !== 14) return;
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (!sheet.getName().match(/^(11th Grade)$/i) || e.range.offset(0, -10).getValue() !== 'Success') return;
  try {
    const targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName('Closed Cases');
    if (!targetSheet) throw new Error('Target sheet cannot be found.');
    targetSheet.insertRowBefore(2);
    sheet.getRange(`${e.range.rowStart}:${e.range.rowStart}`)
      .moveTo(e.source.getRange('Closed Cases!A2'));
    sheet.deleteRow(e.range.rowStart);
  } catch (error) {
    e.source.toast(error.message, 'moveRowConditionally_', 30);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

The version above makes no `SpreadsheetApp` calls unless the edit took place in column `N` and the new value in the cell is `true`, as in a ticked checkbox. Only when those two conditions are met, it will make two API calls to check whether the edit took place on `'11th Grade'`. If that condition is met as well, it will make another two calls to check whether the value in column `D` is `Success`. If that condition is met as well, it will move the row, using another five API calls.

See these [onEdit(e) optimization tips](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/155429/269219).

Comment: I don't know where the success part came from for column D.  That was notes from a script I copied.  All I want to do is column N (14) when checked needs to move from 11th Grade to Closed Cases.  Nothing seems to work.  Not even the script above??

Comment: Column D is specified in the question. You can remove the `|| e.range.offset(0, -10).getValue() !== 'Success'` bit if needed. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/173119/edit) the question as appropriate. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sadly this doesn't execute when I check the box??  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The `onEdit(e)` function will run automatically when you edit the spreadsheet. If you are using the script I gave you, it will execute. Perhaps you mean that no rows move when you tick a checkbox? That's not the same as "does not execute." Make sure you are editing a sheet whose name is spelled exactly `11th Grade` with no leading or trailing spaces, letter case differences, or the like. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Nothing copies and nothing deletes.  It does nothing when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: The tab is called 11th Grade.  The sheet has a much longer name.  The copy and paste needs to go from one tab to another.  Not one spreadsheet to another.

Comment: In Google Sheets, a tab is called a sheet. Consider sharing a [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).

Comment: Here is my test spreadsheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pLcQfE7Q3jEQ1toCmUMjh8APM2hNYnQ4wl-veXV7BMs/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks. The sample spreadsheet does not have the script I gave you. It has your original script, so it is no wonder it continues to behave the same way. The question continues to specify that column D must be `Success`. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/173119/edit) the question so that it states the actual requirements you have.

Comment: Ok there were merged fields that i had to resolve.  So, now that works, but it is overwriting the last record now instead of adding a row??

Comment: Correct.  It overwrites the last thing.  Also, I had the top row frozen and it messes that up also.

Comment: I fixed it!  You are AMAZING!  Thank you so so much!

Comment: Replace `targetSheet.insertRowAfter(1)` with `targetSheet.insertRowBefore(2)`.

Comment: I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)